# Disabling OnTouch / OnTouchListener on screen

Tags: android

I have two views where I should not allow the user to do on touch, they can just type. How can I disable any on touch events for the view?.

Comment: view.setClickable(false);

Comment: I can still swipe the screen with my finger setting the view.setClickable(false);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Try this way**

***Set touchListener and return true in both***

```
view1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                return true;
            }
        });

view2.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

```
view.setOnTouchListener(null);
```

Comment: AFAIK, setOnTouchListener to null simply means that there is no attached listener, so the event goes straight to the view.  Won't suppress anything. Am I wrong about this?